# How to save credentials in app to allow AutoFill feature?

Tags: ios, swift, credentials, autofill

I want my app to save username and password data e.g. at the first login or registration, so later when user tries to log in again it will be offered by the os to auto fill the form. So this is similar when app offers credentials saved in safari, but I also want my app to save this credentials if the login happens there. According to apple documentation I think it should be possible:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/shared_web_credentials/managing_shared_credentials

> If the user can create new accounts in your app, you should save the
>   user name and password to the shared web credentials. In this way, the
>   user can easily access the account from Safari, as well as from within
>   your app. You can save the user’s name and password to the shared web
>   credentials using the SecAddSharedWebCredential(*:*:*:*:) function as
>   shown.

However when I do this:

```
SecAddSharedWebCredential(domain as CFString, username as CFString, password as CFString) { error in
      if let error = error {
          print(error)
      }
}
```

I get the following error printed out:

*Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-909 "Autofill is not enabled in Safari settings" UserInfo={NSDescription=Autofill is not enabled in Safari settings}*

Comment: I want to share credentials that was used to logged in inside the app, not in a website, this is the point of my question.

Comment: The part you highlighted is specifically about sharing login credentials between an app and an associated website.  _"In this way, the user can easily access the account from Safari, as well as from within your app"_.  What I linked previously about [Shared Web Credentials](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/shared_web_credentials) is necessary to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll certify who you are, via Apple, when you create your app, to prove the following:

> 1. That your app will be using the Associated Domains capability.
> 2. That your Team ID is, in fact, valid.

Check out this tutorial for help [How To Secure Your App’s Passwords with Safari AutoFill in iOS 8](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2044-how-to-secure-your-app-s-passwords-with-safari-autofill-in-ios-8)